# Map Annotations ars displaying with incorrect custom pin images

Tags: objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

This is my first question on this site.

My code is implemented in the following function using iOS 6 Mapkit, Objective-C.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

I have ONLY TWO annotations with custom pin images. One red pin and the other a orange pin. The red pin is closer to the user's current location within device map area and the other orange pin is 30 miles away (outside current map context). I am using different colors based on the data behind each pin.

Problem: Custom images for annotations are switching images.

Using all the tips on this site which includes usage of dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier, etc attached is my code.

On the very first display of the map on app launch, the error I see is that the orange pin displays on the device map and the red one is displayed outside. This is incorrect because the red image should have displayed on the device map.

### If I tap the 'Find Me' button on the map to refresh my current location the red pin displays on the map which is now correct. When I tap 'Find Me' again, the red pin switches out to orange pin-- and it keeps switching or toggling pin image colors.

```
if (PinColor == 0) {
            MKAnnotationView* pinview = (MKAnnotationView *)[self._mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

            if (nil == pinview) {                    

                MKAnnotationView* view = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];

            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

            view.opaque = YES;
            view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redpin.png"];

            [view setCanShowCallout:YES];                

            if (self.newPinAdded) {
                [view setSelected: YES];                    
            }

            return view;
        }

        return pinview;            
    }
    else {

        MKAnnotationView* pinview = (MKAnnotationView *)[self._mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"Orangeidentifier"];

        if (nil == pinview) {                

            MKAnnotationView* view = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Orangeidentifier"];

            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

            view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin glabensmall.png"]; //orange pin

            view.opaque = YES;
            [view setCanShowCallout:YES];


            if (self.newPinAdded) {
                [view setSelected: YES];                    
            }

            return view;
        }

        return pinview;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is a common one. Where is PinColor set? The mapview map ask for the annotationView to draw an annotation at any time for any annotation. If PinColor is set to 0 by some other method and then the mapview wants to draw an annotation *any annotation* it will draw a red pin. What you need to do is check which annotation you are drawing and then use the right colour for it. You can check the annotation by reading its title or if it is your own annotation class there may be some other property you can use.

SideNote: There are a few lines you've repeated for both pin version, you should have them outside the IF statement and cut out some lines. And you should use the mapView that `viewForAnnotation` give you:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation{

MKAnnotationView* pinview = nil;
if (annotation is the red one) {
    pinview = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
    if (nil == pinview) {                 
        pinview = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        pinview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redpin.png"];
     }        
} else {
   pinview = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"Orangeidentifier"];
    if (nil == pinview) {                
        pinview = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Orangeidentifier"];
        pinview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin glabensmall.png"]; //orange pin           
    }
}

[pinview setCanShowCallout:YES];                

pinview.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

pinview.opaque = YES;
if (self.newPinAdded) {
    [pinview setSelected: YES];                    
}

}
```

Comment: I am not setting any PinColor. Even the red pin that shows up is my custom red pin and not the standard red pin that may come by default in the mapkit.

Comment: Your code starts with `if(PinColor == 0)`. When - you produce a red image else you produce an orange image. The trouble is you're not changing PinColor to match the annotation you are drawing.

Comment: Perfect answer. Your answer that mentioned that I should check the annotation attributes (i.e., annotation.title or annotation.subtitle) before I set the corresponding image was very helpful. I updated my annotation.title to accommodate text that would help me do just that and now it works fine. Appreciate the quick help.

Comment: Glad to be of service. Now you need to click the Tick/Check mark next to the answer so everyone knows it has been solved (and so I get points :) )